# SQL SERVER: Get total days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I'm trying to get the total number of days between two days:

```
1/1/2011
3/1/2011

RETURN
62
```

Is it possible to do in SQL Server?

Comment: Number of days *between* 1/1 and 3/1 would **never** return 62 in our current calendar. It would either return 58 or 59. Even if you include the start day and end day, that would be 60 or 61.

Comment: And if you're not in the USA, it will return 2 days.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

`PRINT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2011', '3/1/2011')` will give you what you're after.

This gives the number of times the midnight boundary is crossed between the two dates.  You may decide to need to add one to this if you're including both dates in the count - or subtract one if you don't want to include either date.

Comment: It also proceeds datetime and datetime2 like a charm as I can see in my results.

Answer (score 42):

[SQL Server DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2007-05-05 12:10:09.3312722';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2009-05-04 12:10:09.3312722'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate);
```

Answer (score 18):

You can try this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2011', '3/1/2011')
```

Answer (score 17):

See [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '2011/1/1'
DECLARE @enddate date = '2011/3/1'
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate)
```

Answer (score 14):

Another date format

```
select datediff(day,'20110101','20110301')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, startdate, enddate) AS DayCount

Example : SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '11/30/2019', GETDATE()) AS DayCount
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do same thing Store Procedure then you need to apply below code.

```
select  (datediff(dd,'+CHAR(39)+ convert(varchar(10),@FromDate  ,101)+ 
 CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39)+ convert(varchar(10),@ToDate  ,101) + CHAR(39) +')) 
 Daysdiff
```

where @fromdate and @todate is Parameter of the SP

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @FDate DATETIME='05-05-2019' /*This is first date*/
 GETDATE()/*This is Current date*/
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY,(@LastDate),GETDATE())) As DifferenceDays/*this query will return no of days between firstdate & Current date*/
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Code-only answers can often be difficult to interpret.