# How do you count the number of days between two dates excluding the extra day in leap years

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, leap-year

[image]

In the picture I count the number of days between two dates excluding the extra day of the leap years.

How can this be done in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: i can not answer my own question i only got 9 reputations

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER: Get total days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068017/sql-server-get-total-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: @g2_player But you still can edit your question and add comments. Please, show us the query you used to get your results.

Comment: im looking for another solutions

Comment: It is hard to tell if the solution I have provided is "another solution" or not if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: If you always count full years, just count the difference in years and multiply that by 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build yourself a calendar table storing one row for each date along with the extra information you need about that date. To support your query it could look like.

```
create table Calendar
(
  TheDate date primary key,
  LeapDay bit not null
)
```

Your query would then be.

```
select count(*)
from Calendar
where TheDate >= @StartDate and
      TheDate < @EndDate and
      LeapDay = 0
```

One way to fill your calendar table with some data:

```
with Numbers(Number) as
(
  select top(11000) row_number() over(order by 1/0)
  from sys.all_objects as o1, sys.all_objects as o2
), Dates(TheDate) as
(
  select dateadd(day, Number-1, cast('2000-01-01' as date))
  from Numbers
)
insert into Calendar(TheDate, LeapDay)
select TheDate,
       case when datepart(month, TheDate) = 2 and 
                 datepart(day, TheDate) = 29
         then 1
         else 0
      end
from Dates
```

If you don't want to create a permanent table to support your query you can build one in a CTE.

```
with Dates(TheDate) as
(
  select top(datediff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)) 
    dateadd(day, row_number() over(order by 1/0)-1, @StartDate)
  from sys.all_objects as o1, sys.all_objects as o2
)
select count(*)
from Dates as D
where not (datepart(month, D.TheDate) = 2 and datepart(day, D.TheDate) = 29);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18324)