# Checking date with less than or equal to 10 days

Tags: sql, date, to-char

```
Select projectname
from project
where to_char(start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_char(end_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') <= 10;
```

Hi, so i want to get a project that is less than or equal to 10 days long, I am new to SQL, not sure if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER: Get total days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068017/sql-server-get-total-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: I see, Sorry can I ask one more question here, What if i want to get between 10-40 days.

Comment: Please check that i have modiefied the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to change the following thing in your Code

```
Select 
     projectname
FROM 
      project
WHERE
       DATEDIFF(DAY,start_date,end_date) <= 10;
```

fOR DAys between 10 to 40 just modify the code

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,start_date,end_date) <= 10 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,start_date,end_date) >= 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work e.g.

```
20150101 - 20141231 = 8870!
```

So, as others have said, perform the date arithmetic on the ***date*** objects, and then compare to a number.